# php script display order

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, widget

I have this code to generate a rating list in wordpress, i can get the rating for each company in the list but i cannot order the list in descending order and limit the number of the post to 5.. any suggestion please?

```
 <?php
$reviews = apply_filters( 'glsr_get_reviews', [], [
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_key',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'page', // change this as needed
    'posts_per_page' => 5, // change this as needed
]);

foreach( $reviews as $review ) {
    $reviewHtml = $review->build(); ?>
           
    <p><?php echo $reviewHtml->assigned_to; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $reviewHtml->rating; ?></p>
    <?php echo '<br/>'; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

thanks a lot

Comment: did you want the element of `$reviews` to be sorted backward and then show only the first 5 element from the array?

Comment: yes, i want that the $reviews sort the items in descending order and just the first 5 ratings, actually is showing like this [link]https://ibb.co/G7FyHxJ

Answer (score 0):

since you want to sort the array in descending order and display only the first five element the following code will do it for you. but i should explain what i did.

1. First i reversed the array using `array_reverse()` function which will sort the array elements in descending order.
2. Then i initialized the variable called `$limit` to limit the number of element to be displayed.
3. i added conditional `if` statement in `foreach` loop to break out of the foreach loop when the `$limit` is reached it's max.
   Let us know if it worked for you you can just copy and paste the following code

```php
    <?php
    $reviews = apply_filters( 'glsr_get_reviews', [], [
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_key',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'page', // change this as needed
        'posts_per_page' => 5, // change this as needed
    ]);
    $reviews=array_reverse($reviews);//reverse the array itself.
    $limit=0;//initializing counter to track the number of review displayed.
    foreach( $reviews as $review ) {
        $reviewHtml = $review->build(); ?>  
        <p><?php echo $reviewHtml->assigned_to; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $reviewHtml->rating; ?></p>
        <?php 
            echo '<br/>';
            wp_reset_postdata();
            $limit++;//increasing the limit position to the review that is already processd.
            if($limit==5){//check if limit is reached you can change this limit to whatever you need.
            break;//break the loop after 5 review has been displayed.
            }
        } 
    ?>
```

Comment: unfortunately this script doesn't return any information, any rating item is displayed

Comment: it doesn't show any data at all? or it shows all data?

Comment: hi @Dav could you please show me the result of `print_r($reviews)` after `array_reverse($reviews)`